# View Controller Cannot Find Segue With Identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue, identifier

I have 3 view controllers in a part of my storyboard. I also have 2 push segues, one switches the first view controller to the second one, and the other one switches the second view controller to the third one.

I perform both segues programmatically, and I have set all three view controllers to use the same custom class ( Called `RegViewController` ).

Everything works fine with the first segue, but the second one throws an exception saying

```
Crash: Receiver (<RegViewController: 0xab74b50>) has no segue with identifier 'a'
```

I set the identifier for second segue to "a" to make sure it is short and I'm not making any mistake.

Anyways, I'm sure that my view controller has a push segue with that identifier and I dunno if I'm making any mistake logically !

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem :

Assigning 3 view controllers to same custom class, results in errors when you're trying to perform a segue, because the segue with desired identifier is not created from every view controller using that custom class. Using different custom classes would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check your segue identifier. because your segue identifier doesn't same in your code or you are declared identifier name different on your storyboard

[image]

Comment: I just mentioned that I'm "SURE" that those identifiers match !

Comment: I had posted my crash line code in my question.
BTW, I found the problem and solved it. Posted answer above.

P.S:Thanks for your patience in answering my rookie questions.